# Does 32-bit GeSWall protect 64-bit Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, security, 64-bit, firewall

[GeSWall](http://www.gentlesecurity.com/geswall.html) provides excellent Windows security, but there's no 64-bit version. It works on 32-bit Windows 7, and 64-bit Windows 7 can run 32-bit software, so I was wondering whether it does protect 64-bit Windows 7 as well. Especially as it installed without problem:
[image]

I've rebooted since but don't see any sign of it being active. Am I protected or not?

Comment: Read carefully; i said it *can* run 32-bit software. It doesn't have a 64-bit kernel driver, though, but an error message about that is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the risk (some strangers reported it messing up their systems, but of course didn't provide any details), and apparently 32-bit GeSWall works swimmingly on 64-bit Windows 7:

[image]

That's a screenshot of the console that i manually started. I've told WinPatrol to allow its service and so far my system hasn't locked up or crashed. I guess all the "32-bit only. :(" reviews i read are false.

Disabling the GeSWall service, [WinPatrol](https://web.archive.org/web/20200513200607/https://www.winpatrol.com/) (noted to work in 64-bit Windows 7), Windows Defender, and even Windows Firewall, had no effect on [Comodo HIPS and Firewall Leak Test Suite, CLT v.1.1.0.3](https://personalfirewall.comodo.com/cltinfo.html)'s score of 190/340, though. (Only with [Avira Free Antivirus](https://www.avira.com/) active that score increased to 190/330 by blocking Coat.dll.)

As [GentleSecurity](https://web.archive.org/web/20181012185316/http://www.gentlesecurity.com:80/) appears to have died, perhaps Microsoft's [DropMyRights](https://web.archive.org/web/20130904130520/http://news.cnet.com:80/8301-13554_3-9756656-33.html) is a sufficient replacement. Both should be able to be verified working by using Process Explorer to check whether the SetChangeNotifyPrivilige of a process is set to "Default Enabled", according to [this thread](https://web.archive.org/web/20161021210424/http://www.howtogeek.com:80/forum/topic/verifytest-if-dropmyrights-is-working). According to [this page](https://web.archive.org/web/20150703130859/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/michael_howard/archive/2007/08/13/update-on-dropmyrights.aspx), DMR is only needed on XP, though, which will die in April 2014. Unless Microsoft reverted restrictive Vista features, which might have opened holes that today's drive-by downloads use.

Answer (score 1):

I just went to the GeSWall download page and they list a 64-bit Windows version for both editions:

http://www.gentlesecurity.com/downloads_geswall.html

In any case, as the software uses kernelspace drivers, the 32-bit version will not work on a 64-bit OS and vice versa.

Comment: It also says "Not yet available". There's a YouTube video that flashes red bars on everything, but it wasn't clear whether he was using 32-bit on 64-bit Windows.

Comment: [Running it on 64-bit Vista appears to worry this user.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g_Hh-6iS5oI)

Comment: Also, [Softpedia](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Security/Firewall/GeSWall.shtml) says it's for All versions of Windows, and the only negative review says that it jacks up your system, especially on uninstall.